# Brain is equally important as brawn in sports

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

Any idioms/expressions/phrases which conveys the same idea in the title? Example: In badminton, it's not just how fast or hard you hit the shuttle but you also need to play with smartness to defeat the opponent.

Comment: You might find some inspiration here: http://tinyurl.com/Brains-and-Brawn

Comment: How about "Play hard, play smart"? (and don't forget to "play together" if you play doubles!)

Comment: Saying: "You play like you practice." Phrase: "...student of the game."

Comment: y the we "X is equally important as Y" is ungrammatical. One could use "Just as important as" or perhaps "equally important with", although i don't like that, or "X and Y are equally  important."

Answer (score -1):

Here are some phrases related to this concept:

> Mind over matter
>   Playing with finesse
>   It's not easy being Sweezy.

The last expression will probably only be recognized by fans of the Seattle Seahawks (a particular American professional football team).

J.R. Sweezy was an offensive lineman for the Seattle Seahawks.  Growing up, he played defensive line.  The Seahawks drafted him, and taught him how to play offensive line.  He is a large, fast, "athletic" player.  (He is 6' 5" tall, weighs about 300 pounds, and can run 40 yards in under 5 seconds.)  In other words, he has "brawn", and he is fast.

During his first year as a Seahawk, [the other offensive linemen wore shirts](http://www.seahawks.com/news/2014/11/06/middle-line-shuffling-jr-sweezy-stands-out) that said "It's not easy being Sweezy."  Sweezy had to learn all of the skills and techniques of an offensive lineman.  He also had to learn to think like an offensive lineman -- anticipating the moves of defenders, and being in the right place to protect his quarterback and running backs -- while keeping the aggressive mindset of a defensive lineman.  In other words, retraining your "brain" to play a different position is hard.

[This blog post](http://www.fieldgulls.com/football-breakdowns/2014/11/13/7211865/seahawks-j-r-sweezy-marshawn-lynch-pete-carroll) shows some of the challenges that Sweezy faced in a game during his third year as a Seahawk.  Some are mental, and some are physical.